# How do I use perforce checkpoints?

Tags: perforce

Why is perforce giving this error when I try to create a checkpoint? Can I restore the entire database from just a checkpoint file and the journal file? What am I doing wrong, how does this work? Why the perforce user guide a giant book, and there are no video tutorials online?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Why is perforce giving this error when I try to create a checkpoint?

You specified an invalid prefix (`//.` is not a valid filename).  If you want to create a checkpoint that doesn't have a particular prefix, just omit that argument:

```
p4d -jc
```

This will create a checkpoint called something like `checkpoint.8` in the server root directory (`P4ROOT`), and back up the previous journal file (`journal.7`) in the same location.

> Can I restore the entire database from just a checkpoint file and the journal file?

Yes.  The checkpoint is a snapshot of the database at the moment in time when you took the checkpoint.  The journal file records all transactions made after that point.

If you restore from just the checkpoint, you will recover the database as of the point in time at which the checkpoint was taken.  If you restore from your latest checkpoint **plus** the currently running journal, you can recover the entire database up to the last recorded transaction.

The old journal backups that are created as part of the checkpoint process provide a record of everything that happened in between checkpoints.  You don't need these to recover the latest state, but they can be useful in extraordinary circumstances (e.g. you discover that important data was permanently deleted by a rogue admin a month ago and you need to recover a copy of the database to the exact moment in time before that happened).

The database (and hence the checkpoint/journal) does not include depot file content!  Make sure that your depots are located on reasonably durable storage (e.g. a mirrored RAID) and/or have regular backups (ideally coordinated with your database checkpoints so that you can restore a consistent snapshot in the event of a catastrophe).

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/p4sag/chapter.backup.html

Comment: So the checkpoint/journals are just for the perforce meta data, but do not contain the actual content? How would you recommend restoring/backing up the actual depot file content?

Comment: Just like any other set of files -- zip up all the folders, put them someplace safe.  Use `p4 verify` prior to each backup to make sure that nothing has gone wrong (e.g. a failed disk) since your last backup.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just zip up the entire Server root directory? What's the point of the checkpoints? Or could we just zip up the "streamsdepot" folder and then use the journal/checkpoint to restore the rest? Backing up perforce seems extremely disk space intensive. I can't do nightly backups, it would use way too much disk space. It's like 3 gigs, and our project is going to be 50-100 gigs when it's done, we just simply cant afford that type of disk space for backups daily.

Comment: My original answer covers the purpose of the checkpoint/journal scheme.  I wouldn't recommend necessarily keeping every old backup of depot content; most recent daily backup plus the occasional historical backup is adequate as long as you're verifying regularly.  Note also that most of the data in sequential depot backups is identical (historical revisions don't change!) so if your backup storage is smart enough to dedupe this isn't really a concern.

Comment: With modern technology, I'm not sure that manually backing up depot content is something I'd do, TBH; realtime backup solutions exist now, and the depot archives are accessed very infrequently/sparsely compared to the DB so it's not really a problem to have something periodically accessing them in the background.

Comment: Have you implemented a backup solution for Perforce professionally before? I'm curious how you did it. Also, what's this about realtime backup solutions? Could you explain? :x

Comment: I only ever did support/consulting so haven't had to maintain a backup solution myself.  Back in the old days "offsite backups" meant having a physical drive that somebody took home with them, or having a warehouse full of tapes.  If I had to set up a Perforce server these days for anything beyond a personal project I'd stick the backups and the depot archives in a Dropbox folder or some other automated cloud backup, put the DB and journal on different disks, set up checkpoints (also going into the cloud) on a cronjob, and call it a day.  Safer than a tape warehouse and much easier!

Comment: That makes sense haha. I currently made a script which creates a checkpoint daily, but th e actual depot (the actual content) is harder, it's going to be like 50+ gigs by the end of the project). :(